# How to show SQL server 2000 server roles through an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

what sql query will i need to show the activated server roles in a specific user?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a user has the roles "db_writer", etc, assigned to it?

Comment: im trying to determine what server roles (system admin, security admin, process admin, etc....) a user have..

Answer (score 2):

EXEC sp_helpuser 'username' should do.

Answer (score 1):

THIS SHOULD DO IT:

```
select 'ServerRole' = spv.name, 'MemberName' = lgn.name, 'MemberSID' = lgn.sid
from master.dbo.spt_values spv, master.dbo.sysxlogins lgn
where spv.low = 0 and
      spv.type = 'SRV' and
      lgn.srvid IS NULL and
      spv.number & lgn.xstatus = spv.number
```